# webkit keyframes breaks when minimized

Tags: html, css

Facing a weird issue; trying to create a spinner.
when my css gets minified the format changes for the webkit keyframes; which breaks the code.

CSS file:

```
.newSpinner {   
  margin-top: 21%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.newSpinner > div {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: sk-bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
  animation: sk-bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
}

 .newSpinner .bounce1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.50s;
  animation-delay: -0.50s;
}

 .newSpinner .bounce2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.42s;
  animation-delay: -0.42s;
}

.newSpinner .bounce3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.30s;
  animation-delay: -0.30s;
}

.newSpinner .bounce4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.20s;
  animation-delay: -0.20s;
}

.newSpinner .bounce5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.10s;
  animation-delay: -0.10s;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes sk-bouncedelay {
  0%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform: scale(0) }
  40% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="newSpinner">
        <div class="bounce1"></div>         
        <div class="bounce2"></div>         
        <div class="bounce3"></div>         
        <div class="bounce4"></div>         
        <div class="bounce5"></div>
    </div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zo70h82c/

The Problem happens here: below code is the minified version of the part of the  code that I mentioned above

```
   @-webkit-keyframes sk-bouncedelay {
    0,80%,100% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(0)
    }

    40% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.0)
    }
  }
```

Original:

```
 @-webkit-keyframes sk-bouncedelay {
 0%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform: scale(0) }
 40% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The minified is missing a % after 0.

```
@-webkit-keyframes sk-bouncedelay {
0%,80%,100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0)
}

40% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0)
}
```

}

Comment: You are most welcome! Always takes a fresh pair of eyes to pick out the smallest of issues.

Answer (score 0):

As Levi pointed out the % sign gets removed in minified version; probably it thinks 0 has no value.
The fix for this was to change 0% to 1%  which is not ideal solution but it gets things going.